# Basic auth in Bottle & Sending a file to user's browser

Tags: python, bottle

i'm trying to perform basic authentication in bottle framework

```
def is_authenticated_user(user, password): 
    # This function is called to check if a username/password combination is valid
    return username == 'nikos' and password == ******'
```

and call it as:

```
@app.route( '/file', methods=['POST'] )
@auth_basic( is_authenticated_user ) 
.... 
.... 
filename = request.form.get('filename') return static_file( filename, root='/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files' )
```

I'm having trouble making this work, i dont understnad why i'm getting the error method not allowed. Also is the static_file function the correct way to send a file to the user's browser?

Comment: What are your request headers?

Comment: How can i check what they are to show you?!

Comment: Do `print(request.headers)` in `is_authenticated_user` and show the output.

Comment: Actually i was able to make the basic_auth to work.<br> If you want please help me with this issue which si driving me crazy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466285/method-is-not-allowed-when-i-add-post-as-a-method-in-a-view-function

Comment: Oh and also i cannot retrieve the username given to the prompt as `request.auth.username` nor as `request.auth.user`. How can i grab that value?

Comment: Just left you an answer to your latest question here, hope it helps. Side note: please ask exactly 1 question per question. Here you have asked 3. If you ask more than 1, people will vote to close your questions, because it makes clearly answering them difficult. (Note that I did not vote to close this or downvote it, but others will if you don't stick to this site's conventions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i cannot retrieve the username given to the prompt as request.auth.username nor as request.auth.user. How can i grab that value?

[According to the documentation](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.auth), `request.auth` is a tuple of `(user, password)`. Retrieve the username like this:

```
username = request.auth[0]
```